# Différence entre « vachement » et « drôlement »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Je voudrais connaitre la différence entre [vachement](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/vachement/) et [drôlement](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/drolement/).

Comment: Ils se différencient par les synonymes qui sont listés dans liens que vous avez indiqués.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De nos jours les deux mots ont le même sens et se différencient par leur niveau de langue.

**Drôlement** fait partie du registre familier. Il est dérivé du nom « drôle » qui désignait une personne qui amuse, un bon vivant. De nos jours l'adverbe a perdu son sens propre : « d'une façon comique » et est employé depuis le milieu du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle pour signifier de façon singulière, imprévue, et de là comme adverbe d'intensité. On peut le trouver dans la littérature.

**Vachement** est d'un registre plus populaire. Son emploi comme adverbe d'intensité date de 1930, avant il était uniquement employé comme synonyme de « méchamment<sup>*</sup> ».
*Le dictionnaire du français non conventionnel* (Jacques Cellard et Alain Rey) note que le mot s'est surtout répandu  après 1960 et

> est de loin l'intensif le plus employé (parfois le seul) par une génération entière, et largement accepté dans l'usage familier par la collectivité.

Je pense que les nouvelles générations ont trouvé désormais d'autres marqueurs d'intensité et que le mot est peut-être moins utilisé de nos jours qu'il y a quarante ans.

Il existe deux variantes de vachement :
*[vachtement](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/liste.php?motsclef=vachetement&submit=Gi!&moduless=siterech&exact=1)* et [*vachte*](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=62945)

<sup>À noter que l'adjectif « vache » est encore employé de nos jours pour signifier, de façon familière, « méchant ».</sup>

Comment: Une jolie fleur dans une peau d'vache...

Comment: Wiktionary est d'accord avec toi pour les registres mais j'aurais cru « vachement » plus familier que « drôlement ». Question d'usage qui rend « drôlement » de plus en plus désuet, sans doute.

Answer (score 3):

D'après moi, "vachement" a une valeur quantitative plus forte que "drôlement", en plus d'être d'un registre encore plus familier :

> "Il est vachement intelligent"

est quasi équivalent à

> "Il est drôlement intelligent"

mais permet de donner plus d'intensité.

Il existe cependant un cas où on peut utiliser "drôlement", mais qu'on ne peut pas remplacer par "vachement" :

> "Elle m'a regardé drôlement"

est équivalent à

> "Elle m'a regardé bizarrement"

On décrit ici la *manière* et non l'*intensité*. Pour ce dernier, voici quelques exemples sur [la définition du Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/dr%C3%B4lement/26855).

Comment: Plus "Elle m'a regardé vachement" - méchamment.

Answer (score -3):

Vachement (énormément)

Drôlement ( étrangement )